# Select2 search box cannot get focus when in BootstrapDialog

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I am creating a Select2 this way:

```
function SetSelect(obj, placeholder, url) {
    obj.select2({
        placeholder: placeholder,
        theme: "bootstrap",
        language: "es",
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                // scrolling can be used
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        },
    });
}
```

The  Select2 is placed inside a modal dialog (BootstrapDialog). The problem is that the search input box that is shown in the select cannot get focus. I have read other person that had the same problem but their solutions did not work for me (for example, trying to change the z-index). Is this a bug in Select2? How can I solve it?

Comment: do you have tabindex="-1" on your modal element? If so, try removing it

Comment: Thanks.. that did it. Since this is a BootstrapDialog, I had to modify the JS file in order to remove that attribute. I don't know why that attribute was used.

Comment: @paulitto Please make it as an answer. It worked for me as well.

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas added as an answer, and also added better way to this

Answer (score 20):

Bootstrap modal uses tabindex="-1" html attribute to enforce focus on it.

You can remove this attribute from modal element and it should make select2 search box focusable.

But this can cause problems for some of modal expected behavior as this attribute was added for reason (it might not be able to preserve tabbings as expected, or allow closing dialog on esc key etc)

So better way to do it would be to use "dropdownParent" property of select2, it wouldn't require removing tabindex (took from [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1645#issuecomment-281291488))

```
$("#mySelect").select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
});
```

See also working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/vj2sLnb3/)

Comment: THANKYOU! Was absoutely stumped on this - I couldn't figure out how on earth it could possibly be focusing on the wrong input. Mine didn't work by making the select2 the parent, but when I entered the div I was working in (inside the modal) it worked.